# SQL Server 2008R2 SP1 instance not available for adding features

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

[image: installation screen]

I need to add fulltext capabilities to an existing SQL Server 2008R2 instance but the one I need to upgrade is not actually available. The combobox shows only the one selected, as in the picture. It looks like it could be related to different versions of the two instances but I can't explain why. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you applied a non-public hotfix or patch? I can't find version [10.51.2500.0](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-versions) listed anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem by uninstalling SP2. Then, the instance version got back to the one matching the DVD and I was able to add FullText feature to the default existing one.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mark's comment.  Perhaps the default instance was installed with SQL 2012 (code name denali) beta or release candidate?  If that's the case then you should be able to use that installer to try to add features but older versions of the binaries (like SQL 2008 R2) would not be able to.

Comment: Looking at this resource http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-versions, I can confirm the fact that the default instance was updated with SP1 (windows update). The one I installed after from the dvd still has version R2 RTM. I now suppose this is sort of a bug that hides new versions when it comes to add new features because the dvd installer tries to match its own version number. Can someone confirm this? Any known workarounds?